# JavaFX DatePicker - Controlling display of days of the prev/next month

Tags: javafx, datepicker

I'm working with the dayCellFactory to format the display. I've implemented disabling prev dates, allowing to select Mondays only, and highlighting period upon date selection.

```java
final Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {
        @Override
        public DateCell call(final DatePicker datePicker) {
            return new DateCell() {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item.isBefore(LocalDate.now().minusWeeks(1).plusDays(1))) {
                        setDisable(true);
                        setStyle("-fx-background-color: #d3d3d3;");
                    }
                    else if (item.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.MONDAY) {
                        setDisable(true);
                    }
                    if (selectedDate != null) {
                        LocalDate startDate = selectedDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
                        if (item.isAfter(startDate) && item.isBefore(startDate.plusWeeks(weeksInPeriod))) {
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffc0cb;");
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    };
```

The only thing I can't figure out is how to make only current month's dates to show up on my calendar (not current month as in LocalDate.now().getMonth(), the currently displayed month in the DatePicker popup).